# Scrolling sidebar position on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

How can I make my scrolling sidebar set its correct position on document ready *without* an animation? Keep in mind, I want to keep the animation for general scrolling after page load.

I used .scroll() to trigger a scroll on load but this looks sloppy when halfway down a page and you're waiting for the sidebar to catch up.

http://jsfiddle.net/b4MaJ/1/

```
w.scroll(function () {
    if (w.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: w.scrollTop() - offset.top + 45
        }, function () {
            distance = (footer.offset().top - footer.outerHeight()) - sidebar.offset().top;
            if (distance <= 50) {
                sidebar.stop().animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 250);
            } else {
                sidebar.stop().animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 250);
            }
        });
    } else {
        sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
}).scroll();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `position:fixed;` in `.customerOrder`

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B9FeF/)

```
.customerOrder {
    background: red;
    position:fixed;
    top:30px;
    right:5px;
}
```

Remove Jquery

Comment: I want to keep the animation for general scrolling. It's just on page load, that I want the sidebar to be fixed in its correct position and ready to animate.

Comment: When i refreshed the fiddle. on page load its already fixed in correct position.